# JPA query failed with chained property of embedded class

Tags: hibernate, jpa

JPA 2.0

An entity class with an embeddable class below,

```java
@Embeddable
public class Person {
 private String name;
 // accessors ...
}

@Entity
public class Employee {
 @Id
 private Integer id;
 @Embedded
 private Person person;
 // accessors ...
}
```

JPA query below,

```java
String name = "myname";
String queryStr = "select e from Employee e where e.person.name = :name";
TypedQuery<Employee> query = entityManager.createQuery(queryStr, Employee.class);
query.setParameter("name", name);
query.getResultList();
```

Exception thrown below,

```
org.hibernate.QueryException:  
could not resolve property:    
person.name of: Employee [select e from Employee e where e.person.name = :name]
```

What's wrong with the chained property "e.person.name" of the embedded class in JPA query above?

Comment: Please post the whole code of both entities, from the package statement to the end of the class.

Comment: Thanks. The `@Embeddable` was actually the subclass of a `plain` java class (annotated with neither `@Entity` nor `@MappedSuperclass`), so all its inherited properties were hidden from `JPA mapping`.